# Проблема со swiftmailer на локальном сервере

Tags: php

На локальном сервере установил заглушку fakesandmail(/usr/bin/fakesendmail.sh -bs). Функция mail срабатывает и новые письма появляются в папке-заглушке. Через PhpMailer также. Беру пример из https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html

```
// Sendmail
$transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/bin/fakesendmail.sh -bs');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
 ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
 ->setTo(['receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
 ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
 ;

 // Send the message
 $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Письма в заглушку не отправляются. Ошибок и предупреждений. Я так понимаю, что я передаю неверный параметр в конструкторе Swift_SendmailTransport.
Как исправить?

Comment: Есть какие либо ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок не показывает